# How does attacker Brute force facebook account if there is a limit for tries?

Tags: brute-force, kali-linux

I am wondering how does a user use Kali with python Brute Force Algorithm to  brute force accounts like a facebook account when there are security measure in place like:Pause your try after 3 unsuccessful login?

Edit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsh9_se3UC0

In the above video, the user used Kali and ran a python script that ran a "dictionlist".txt against a specific fb account, so i am wondering why it seemed that the account didnt block the attempt after 3 times?

Comment: Kali is a Linux distribution not a tool for brute-force.

Comment: Sorry i phrased the question badly. I edited it

Comment: @John can you give more details like which Python program  you are using and its source code?

Comment: Your question implies that this is possible, and that Kali has some characteristic that makes it useful for this. If your question had been "how come facebook accounts still get brute forced when there are security measures in place like `Pause your try after 3 unsuccessful logins`?" I would say that criminals usually go after *any* account, and so they try just a few common passwords on millions of accounts.

Comment: The answer is: Sentry MBA.

Comment: @RápliAndrás it does not help when you are targeting a specific account, also I don't think it uses brute-force.

Comment: The question does not say it's a specific account. @John, clarify this?

Comment: Hi sorry i just got home, i was doing some research saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsh9_se3UC0 and it was against a specific fb account, and thats why i was wondering about that.  The user was on Kali and ran a python script that ran a "dictionarylist".txt trying different combo for a specific account. And it didnt "block" him

Comment: Sorry for phrasing the question badly, i edited it. On the video at 1.55 it said trying 879658.... maybe the video is fake or something.. i have no idea.... but that was the reason why i asked the question.

Comment: The video is from 2014. This leads me to believe this was made around the time when Facebook had missing throttling on few actions (http://pwndizzle.blogspot.fi/2014/02/brute-forcing-your-facebook-email-and.html), probably one of them was the recovery code (6 digits, 1 million possibilities) The "attacker" didn't really brute-force the password; he brute-forced this recovery code. Incidentally, a month ago somebody discovered the same issue with Facebook beta installation (More here: http://www.anandpraka.sh/2016/03/how-i-could-have-hacked-your-facebook.html)

Answer (score 1):

They don't.

If an attacker is trying to get into a specific account, he will rely on phishing or malware.

If an attacker is just trying to get working accounts, he will have a wordlist of emails and passwords that he'll try, thereby bypassing the restriction of password attempts simply because it's not being attempted on the same account.

Comment: Please post comment to a comment under the comment not in an unrelated answer. Have a look how SE sites work, how answers and comments are displayed (and hidden, often deleted) and try to imagine that it is not easy to follow loose references. If you can't comment yet, please wait till you can.

Comment: I didn't have the required reputation to post a comment, which in my opinion is stupid, but there you have it.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusing question etc...i wrote the original question because i was doing some research and saw a youtube vid, that the user was on Kali and used a python script that he include a "list".txt for the brute force on a specific account on facebook, so i wondered. This is the vid. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsh9_se3UC0

Comment: He doesn't show the scripts source, nor the password being cracked

Comment: From that, you can't really ascertain much